# jQuery oembed api key issue

Tags: jquery, embed

First really sorry if its a stupud question.

I downloaded jquery oembed from here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/

I used it with out problems many times, till today.

I got an error what never popped up before. The consolde said Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (link)

I went to see whats the problem, copied the given link from the console to the browser and i got this message

```
Embedly has blocked your client ip. Sign up for an API key at http://embed.ly
```

i never experienced this before, and used the plugin lot of times. I never registrated on embedly, and never had this error message

Could please someone tell why is this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because the embeding goes trouh embed.ly use the starfish oembed its the same the only differences (if i recall it right) its not embeding trouh embed.ly.

https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all

P.S Sorry if i recall it wrong it was a really long time i used it

EDIT

oh so sorry, i forgot that they changet it, open up the plugin. find this line `defaultOEmbedProvider: "embed.ly",` it has to be at line 59 or close to it and change it to `defaultOEmbedProvider: "none"` this will make it work native

Comment: you are right, it does use nativ, but its still the same. Strange